# I can't run JAR file?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have created a Java JAR file in NetBeans. I have already run *clean and build* on the program and everything was successful. When I run the program in NetBeans is also successful, but when i locate the JAR file in the NetBeans dist folder and run it, nothing happens. The program doesn't run, and there are no exceptions or messages. Could you please help me understand why.

EDIT: I already solved the problem.

Comment: Are you able to run the JAR file from the command prompt, such as by calling `java -jar myJarFile.jar` - does this show you any errors? Without knowing any further information, it might be caused by NetBeans using a different version of Java to your default Java engine, or possibly there is a different classpath being used?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make executable jar ? You might wanna put your main class in manifest of the jar file.

Something like :

```
Main-Class : file_name_with_main_method
```

Comment: yes. actually did not set the main class of the program because I am making two program this day,. but I will try set the main class of the program and I'll try if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably on Windows :)

One way to "run" a .jar file is to create a Windows File association for ".jar" suffix and the "javaw.exe" command:

1) Go into Windows Explorer and [Browse...] to your .jar file

2) Right-click the .jar file, and select the "open with..." option.

3) Select javaw.exe as above, and see if it runs.

Comment: Hi I already done this I actually downloaded the JRE and make javaw as my default when running a jar file

Comment: Q: Why didn't you mention that in your original post?  Q: have you tried running `java -jar myJarFile.jar` from the command prompt, as suggested above?  What happened?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the Console if you are on a Mac. You can view errors from the Jar launch to understand why it failed.

Comment: Hi how do you check the console using windows?

Comment: To check it on Windows I would suggest just learning to use CMD and be done with it. Modern Java distributions on Windows now apply themselves to the path variable so you can use it pretty well, and for what you need to do, CMD and BASH are very similar.